# Python Pandas: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'

Tags: python, string, pandas, error-handling

Working with dataframe df:

```
Count
1
2
3
4
5
```

Want to add second column, that categorizes everything above 3 as '4+' - needed output:

```
Count | Category
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4+
5        4+
```

This is my code:

```
df['Category'] = df['Count']
df = df.loc[df['Count'] > 3, 'Category'] = '4+'
```

And I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

Comment: FYI - you can also use `df['Category'] = np.where(df['Count'] < 4, df['Count'], '4+')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just go with

```
df['Category'] = df['Count']
df.loc[df['Count'] > 3, 'Category'] = '4+'
```

Comment: thank you - do you mind explainin, what I did wrong?

Comment: I just tried without the "df=" and I get the same error

Comment: Why wouldn't I use the df=?

Comment: You are already assigning using loc when you do df.loc[df['Count'] > 3, 'Category'] = '4+'. When you add df = ...., you are trying to assign twice in the same statement, which obviously wouldn't work

Comment: Is this answer actually working for you @jeangelj? I tried it and got Error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4+'`

Comment: If the column `"Count"` has integers you should do `df['Category'] = df['Count'].apply(str)` first as I stated in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out with:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Count": [1,2,3,4,5]})
df["Category"] = df["Count"].apply(str)
df["Category"][df['Count'] > 3] = "4+"
```

Output would be:

```
>>> df
   Count Category
0      1        1
1      2        2
2      3        3
3      4       4+
4      5       4+
```

Comment: It throws SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Comment: Did you try the only the example I stated or you used your own dataframe? If you dataframe has numbers this should work.

Comment: Please go through this link to understand settingwithcopy warning and why should loc be used. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Comment: Well, that's strange. I tried under Python 2.7 and 3.3 on [pythonanywhere.com](http://www.pythonanywhere.com) and got no warnings from my option.